# Vue component with position: absolute

Tags: css, vue.js, css-position

There is a `Vue-component`.
It's a `div` with some content.
By event, this element must be placed at the given coordinates (relative to the document).

I set styles for it:

```css
return {
    position: "absolute",
    top: `${x}px`,
    left: `${y}px`,
};
```

But if one of the parents of this element has `position: relative` then position calculate relative the parent, not document.

My solution: move the element to the document root.

```
mounted() {
    document.body.appendChild(this.$refs.container);
},
```

It works greate.
But I have questions:

1. Can it be solved using CSS only?
2. What problems can occur when I move the element who rendered in Vue-template?
3. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Could the component itself be moved?

Comment: There is no way I know of that you can do it with css unless you can use `position: fixed` instead.

Comment: ceejayoz, the component is component. It should not know when it will be included and what parents will it have.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a great use case for *portals*. It allows components to exists in some location but the template be renderes somewhere else. Take a look at [portal-vue](https://portal-vue.linusb.org/)

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(PortalVue);

Vue.component('MyComponent', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>First</h1>
      <portal to="destination">
        <h1>Second</h1>
      </portal>

    </div>
  `,
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/portal-vue@2.1.5/dist/portal-vue.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="portal-destination">
    <portal-target name="destination"></portal-target>
  </div>
  <div><my-component></my-component></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Phillip, thank you! It mean I must make a target in the body? But I make component. It should not know when it will be included and what parents will it have.

Comment: Using portal-vue you can create a target anywhere in your application and use that as a destination.